# How to insert server timestamp in Firestore document using REST?

Tags: rest, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to insert a document using a REST call to [Firestore createDocument](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument) method. One of the fields is a timestamp field that should be set on the server. With Android SDK it's as simple as annotating a `Date` field with `@ServerTimestamp` and keeping it null — now how do I do it in REST?

```
{
  "fields": {
    "timezoneId": {
      "stringValue": "Europe\/London"
    },
    "city": {
      "stringValue": "London"
    },
    "timestamp": {
      "timestampValue": "???"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried using `null`, `0`, empty string, `timestamp` — everything fails with an error requiring the standard RFC3339 format (e.g. `2018-01-31T13:50:30.325631Z`). Is there any placeholder value I can use, or any way to obtain that timestamp?

Comment: In case there is no way to indicate you want the server timestamp in a REST call, you can apply the server timestamp to *all* new documents (regardless of origin) using a Cloud Functions Firestore onCreate trigger that applies the timestamp in a subsequent update.

Comment: Yeah, but I thought maybe there was a way. IIRC, with Firebase Realtime Database there was a way (using a reserved field/value).

Comment: Yes, in RTDB there is a special token for that. Maybe there is something similar for Firestore that's just not documented, or maybe it was an omission. I bet someone from the Firestore team will jump in here tomorrow.

Comment: Just stumbled the same problem, still no solution seems like :( The fact that reserved fields createTime & updateTime for each document are not supported by iOS & Android SDK (only NODE JS) makes it worse.

Answer (score 2):

The Android SDK doesn't execute a `createDocument` request when creating the document. Instead it uses the [`write`](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firestore/firestore/v1beta1/firestore.projects.databases.documents.write) request to issue an `update` and a `transform` request at the same time. If you are wanting to only use `createDocument`, then the answer is no.

Your payload would look something like this:

```
{
  "writes": [
    {
      "update": {
        "name": "projects/{projectId}/databases/{databaseId}/documents/{document_path}",
        "fields": {
          "timezoneId": {
            "stringValue": "Europe\/London"
          },
          "city": {
            "stringValue": "London"
          }
        }
      },
      // ensure the document doesn't exist
      "currentDocument": {
        "exists": false
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": {
        "document": "projects/{projectId}/databases/{databaseId}/documents/{document_path}",
        "fieldTransforms": [
          {
            "fieldPath": "timestamp",
            "setToServerValue": "REQUEST_TIME"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The only downside to adding documents this way is you would need to generate the `Document` ID yourself (the SDK's generate them). I hope this helps.