# Firestore Rules verify timestamp with a Flutter client

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to send the **creation time** of a Firestore document through the client and verify the time with *Firestore Rules* to avoid Cloud Functions calls (pricing).

#### Scenario

I am testing requests from clients against Firestore rules like this:

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.TIMEFIELD == request.time;
```

The request contains a `TIMEFIELD` that has a timestamp, just like `request.time`.

#### Problem

Apparently the request time and the time I am setting as a field right before sending the request are not equivalent, which makes this comparison impossible.

The following is the defition of `request.time` from the documentation.

> [When the request was received by the service.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time)

I wonder if there is a way to set a field in a document equal to `request.time`.

*I am unable to use **server side** timestamps because of [an issue with Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13905).*
Because of that I need to know how I could possibly validate client side timestamps like `time.now` with Firestore Rules.

Comment: allow create: if request.resource.data.TIMEFIELD == request.time; any reason behind this? Why do you want to validate the time?

Comment: @AngusTay Because the timestamp is important for the product and no one should be able to manipulate the time. I think that this is the main reason behind Firebase Security Rules in general.

Comment: It seems this question is Flutter specific - and maybe fixed since 2018? If so, would you care to mention Flutter in the title and adding it as a tag?  Maybe the whole issue is fixed, in which case this question serves only as historic evidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been implemented into the Flutter plugin for Cloud Firestore:

```dart
FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Using this as a field's value will assign a timestamp equal to `request.time` to the field, server-side.

You can find out more about it in the [API reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldValue/serverTimestamp.html) for [`cloud_firestore`](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Timestamp` to add constraints to the time field ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Timestamp)).

Here is an example of how to ensure that the change was within a certain amount of seconds:

```
function withinSeconds(secs) {
  return request.resource.data.TIMEFIELD.seconds() - request.time.seconds() <= secs
    && request.resource.data.TIMEFIELD.seconds() - request.time.seconds() >= -secs
}
```

### Edit

The above is for setting the value within a threshold of the `request.time`.

You can also just use the REST API in the mean time. Just make a `write` request that includes an `update` and a `transform`. The `transform` is where you would set the server timestamp. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firestore/firestore/v1beta1/firestore.projects.databases.documents.write) is a tool to help understand how to build the requests.

Comment: Yeah I misunderstood the question. I just updated the answer.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610665/how-to-insert-server-timestamp-in-firestore-document-using-rest/51830552#51830552) is an answer I previously wrote with an example of how to insert a Timestamp using the REST API. It might help you with understanding the payload structure. You can also just execute the Web SDK and look at your "Network" (in the console) tab to see the payloads generated.

Comment: This is not the (best) way to do it. `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` will deliver a perfectly accurate timestamp instead.

Answer (score 0):

you'd first have to remember the creation (or last updated) timestamp:

```
firestore().collection("items").add({
    ....
    created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
});
```

in order to let the client know of the timestamp, which you are trying to compare later on.

Comment: the question did not mention Flutter, nor any platform ... while this would be the JS docs (proofing, that this value at least exists on the server-side): https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot there is a Dart/Flutter plug-in, which provides access: https://github.com/pauldemarco/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_firestore/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/firestore ...and your business logic should consider, that the server-timestamps are what actually counts (there might have some offset relative to the client-side timestamps). basically, you'd need to update the document, and then update the new timestamp client-side. just add a function which updates the one and another, which compares these two. similar to a `SyncAdapter`