# Does Firestore REST API support equivalent values to the SDK's FieldValue?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use the Firestore REST API but struggle to find documentation regarding methods from the SDK that I was hoping would be available.

These include the likes of `FieldValue.increment()` and `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` ([Firebase documentation: FieldValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue)). Are these possible through the REST API? I cannot find any documentation relating to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The REST API is not necessarily easy to use, since you're essentially seeing the wire protocol of gRPS calls. For that reason the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) says:

> If you are using a gRPC-supported language, consider using the RPC API rather than the REST API.

That said, operation such as `FieldValue.increment` are available in the REST API in the form of so-called transforms, which are additional operations that are performed on the server after the actual setting of the value(s) (still as part of the same write operation). In this case you're looking for a `FieldTransform` operation, as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/Write#FieldTransform).

I highly recommend studying the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610665/how-to-insert-server-timestamp-in-firestore-document-using-rest) of using server-side timestamps (which is quite similar), and liberally using the [Firestore API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firestore/firestore/v1/).

Comment: Thank you, all your provided linked are useful and insightful. This should do the trick!

Comment: Following up with these links, the server-side timestamp example you provided looks like it would be most suited, but I'm struggling to determine the path and request type to raise to perform one of these "write" operations. Can you advise?

Comment: "struggling" is not very actionable here. If you're still trying over REST, please edit your question to show what you have now based on the resources I provided.

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify. The example looks like what I need, but I can't test it because I can't figure out the API request to call (the URI), and the link to "write" within the upvoted answer is a 404. This [_Write_ documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/Write) is a great reference, but I am still unsure where to issue the request (for example, it doesn't work the the API's `:runQuery` request)