# How should a "write" request be structured for Firestore REST API (v1beta1)?

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

Based on the [Google Discovery document](https://firestore.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1beta1), and [RPC reference](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1beta1#google.firestore.v1beta1.Write), it appears that the **:write** resource should be available for Firestore database interactions, but performing such a request to my (`POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/[my project]/databases/(default)/documents:write`) results in:

```
[
  {
    "error": {
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Invalid value (Object), ",
      "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
      "details": [
        {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
          "fieldViolations": [
            {
              "description": "Invalid value (Object), "
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Is this possible? A [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51830552/12488775) alludes to this being available as a means of field transforms, the same reason I require this, but I cannot construct valid a JSON body to succeed in the request. Currently, variations on the following don't work as expected when trying a minimum successful response:

```
{
    "writes": [
        {
            "update": {
                "name": "projects/{projectId}/databases/[my project]/documents/exampleId",
                "fields": {
                    "example": {
                        "integerValue": 100
                    },
                    "timestamp": {
                        "nullValue": null
                    }
                },
                "transform": {
                    "document": "projects/[my project]]/databases/(default)/documents/examples/exampleId",
                    "fieldTransforms": [
                        {
                            "fieldPath": "timestamp",
                            "setToServerValue": "REQUEST_TIME"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use documents:commit instead of documents:write

also the name field should be in this format:

```
"name": "projects/projectID/databases/(default)/documents/collectionName/DocumentId"
```

See [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/lRfSnXqt4yU/kEvDYhd2AgAJ).

Comment: Thank you @gerry, I will try this. From your post, did you resolve generating IDs within a request (or require multiple requests) when limited to REST API use? I am in the same situation.

Comment: Using `:commit` works, thanks @gerry. While the `name` and `fields` fields are supported, I still find this doesn't appear to match the **Write** structure, inc. `currentDocument` and `transform`, returning RPC BadRequest responses if they are included. Have you experienced this?

Comment: @Rhys, I did not resolve generating the auto IDs. For our current use case we are self generating IDs based upon criteria in the database we are moving to Firestore. We don't have the volume of data where we anticipate this being a problem.

Comment: I have not used either of currentDocument or transform.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that you should use the [v1 version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1.projects.databases.documents) of the REST API, not the betas.

To create a document, you would use the [`createDocument`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument) method, while to update a document you would use the [`patch`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/patch) one.

---

For the document creation you should therefore make a POST HTTP Request to the following URL

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<your-project-id>/databases/(default)/documents/<the-desired-collection>
```

with the following Request body:

```
{
  fields: {
    example: {
      integerValue: 100
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @Renaud. It doesn't look like create/patch support field transforms, which I may not have emphasised enough in the question as to why I am seeking the `update` object support.